How to play audio file from Google Drive using flutter audioplayers?
I am uploading recorded audio on google drive, then I am trying to play it, with formatted URI
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
late AudioPlayer _player;
final modifiedUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/$id/preview';
await _player.play(UrlSource(modifiedUrl, mimeType: 'audio/mp4'));

After which i get the following error:
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26589): reset
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): reset
V/MediaPlayer(26589): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(26589): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaHTTPService(26589): MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@1289ca3): Cookies: null
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26589): setVolume: left 1.000000  right 1.000000
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26589): setLooping: 0
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): MediaPlayer::setLooping
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): setVideoSurfaceTexture
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): prepareAsync
V/MediaHTTPService(26589): makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@7168ba0
V/MediaHTTPService(26589): makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@1289ca3): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@7168ba0 Cookies: null
I/MediaHTTPConnection(26589): setReadTimeout and setConnectTimeout with 8000ms
I/MediaHTTPConnection(26589): response code = 401
E/MediaHTTPConnection(26589): java.io.IOException
E/MediaHTTPConnection(26589):   at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:389)
E/MediaHTTPConnection(26589):   at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.getMIMEType(MediaHTTPConnection.java:499)
E/MediaHTTPConnection(26589):   at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:161)
E/MediaHTTPConnection(26589):   at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1220)
E/MediaHTTPConnection(26589):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)
W/MediaHTTPConnection(26589): request failed with error => 401
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1005
E/MediaPlayerNative(26589): error (1, -1005)
E/MediaPlayer(26589): Error (1,-1005)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26589): reset
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): reset
I/flutter (26589): AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
I/flutter (26589):  UrlSource(url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qG8yH_o4bru3jib06HVThvCu1sdHqB43/preview, mimeType: audio/mp4), 
I/flutter (26589):  PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {what:1}, MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {extra:-1005}, null)
V/MediaPlayer(26589): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(26589): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer(26589): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(26589): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26589): release
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): setListener
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): disconnect
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): destructor
V/MediaPlayerNative(26589): disconnect

However, if i put that url in browser it starts playing.
Can you advice how can i achieve audio streaming in my flutter application??
